# Vim unique option

Tags: linux, vim

I would like to open a file in a gvim window, but only if the file is not open in vim already. Preferedly by using commandline options. I tried

```
file=...
gvim --cmd ':drop $file'
```

But this opens an additional visible new empty window in my linux environment if the file is already open. Is there a different option/command to achieve the unique behaviour of other editors.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ gvim --remote filename
```

Does exactly what you describe. You may need a couple of things in your `~/.vimrc`, though:

```
set switchbuf=useopen,usetab
```